# D3.js change title text when mouseover a bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to display multiple bar charts (30+ charts) similar to the example here: http://phrogz.net/js/d3-playground/#MultiBars_HTML  As the user hovers over a bar I want to change the title of just the chart the user is interacting with, with information about the value the user is hovering over.

So if I add something like:

```
bars.on('mouseover', mouseoverfunc);

function mouseoverfunc(d, i) {
// update the title just for this chart..not all charts
a.select("h2").text(function (d) { return "hello"; });
}
```

So knowing the mouseover is on the bar [d3.select(this)], how do I select the parent so I can change just the title of one chart?  There is a very similar example here: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/minnesota.html that I'm trying to replicate in D3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to assign an attribute to your title divs that let you find them with a select statement, something like:

```
d3.select("[parentBarChartID="+d.id+"]")
```

in your `mouseoverfunc`.

Alternatively, you couldmake your DOM elements hierarchical such that you can traverse using this.parentNode.childNodes, looping over all children until you find the title node (see how to loop over child nodes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.childNodes).

Comment: Okay, I like the idea of assigning an attribute on the title for each chart.  But, my 'mouseoverfunc' function has the parameter i and d, the index of the bar and the bar value.  I don't know what chart the user is interacting with to know which attribute to change.  I'm looking into your suggestion of traversing the DOM now.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case, if the `d` in `mouseoverfunc(d)` is the bar element (shouldn't be the numerical value), you should be able to use `d.parentNode.id` to get the correct ID to use in your `d3.select` statement that I suggested above.

Comment: You can also look at `d3.event` if the `d` above doesn't have what you need. I think the property would be `d3.event.sourceEvent.target`. (Use `console.dir(d3.event)` with firebug or your web console open to inspect the event's properties.)

Comment: Great, after using firebug I was able to inspect the DOM and get to the parentElement from the mouseoverfunc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following two examples should show you how to individually select any bar and trigger a callback that selects any specific item...

- "[Multiple D3 Horizontal Bar Charts Mixed In With HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2141479)"
- "[Multiple D3 Vertical Bar Charts Mixed In With HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2164562)"

You'll notice in the callback functions "synchronizedMouseOver" and "synchronizedMouseOut" that they trigger the change of multiple objects on the SVG canvas... An individual bar, a legend bullet, and a legend text string.  You would use the same methodology to change a chart title.

I hope this helps.

Frank